# "Clustering" of correlation matrix

Tags: r

I would like to "tidy" or "cluster" correlations of a given data matrix in such a way that highly correlated variables appear next to each other. For example, if I have data like this:

```
n <- 1000
my_corr <- matrix(c(1,   0.8, 0.8, 0,   0, 0,
                    0.8, 1,   0.8, 0,   0,   0,
                    0.8, 0.8, 1,   0,   0, 0,
                    0,   0,   0,   1,   0.9, 0.9,
                    0,   0,   0,   0.9, 1,   0.9,
                    0,   0,   0,   0.9, 0.9, 1), nrow = 6)
my_chol <- chol(my_corr)
# Edit: Rui is right, I should have used replicate
#d <- do.call(cbind, lapply(1:6, function(x) rnorm(n)))
d <- replicate(6, rnorm(n))
d <- d %*% my_chol
d <- cbind(d[, -c(2, 4)], d[, 2], d[, 4])
```

The correlations are like so:

```
library(GGally)
ggcorr(d)
```

[image]

However, "want" would look like this:

[image]

How do I do that if I don't know the solution/is it possible with a pre-built function?

Comment: Instead of `do.call/cbind/lapply` try `d2 <- replicate(6, rnorm(n))`. If you `set.seed` the results are `identical`. Even `sapply(1:6, function(x) rnorm(n))` is nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`corrplot` has this option:

```
my_corr <- matrix(c(1,   0.8, 0.8, 0,   0, 0,
                    0.8, 1,   0.8, 0,   0,   0,
                    0.8, 0.8, 1,   0,   0, 0,
                    0,   0,   0,   1,   0.9, 0.9,
                    0,   0,   0,   0.9, 1,   0.9,
                    0,   0,   0,   0.9, 0.9, 1), nrow = 6)

corrplot::corrplot(my_corr, order = "AOE", type = "lower", method = "color")
```

[image]

[Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html), you can pretty much change everything and make it more like `ggcorr`.

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: remember that you need to pass a `corr` matrix to `corrplot`

Comment: Yes, found that (and tried). I really didn't know how to get on track, but that is everything I hoped for.